# Change DIV color background depending on MIN and MAX array values?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

In brief explanation, I am retrieving values from an array by using an AJAX call. Green to Red colors background will be displayed depending on the number "aht_value". The colors are being displayed correctly because I manually putted the values in the calculation below. That being said, in my "function conv(x)" I want the values to be dynamic.

Theres 3 things that I am trying to achieve in my code but can't get it to work. So, here is my [fiddle for better understanding](http://jsfiddle.net/L3dppyea/1/)

1. Fetch MIN and MAX value from the array in "aht_value". For later use in the conv(x) function.
2. If aht_value is equal to "NA" display a white background.
3. Make the values not surpass the little squares.. how can I center them so the number doesnt overlap?

and here is an array example being retrieved from my "show_aht.php".

Array:

```
[ 
  {
   "username":"OXGOR",
   "aht_value":"241",
   "station":"B20"
  }
  {
   "username":"AISAI2",
   "aht_value":"199",
   "station":"B21"
  },
  {
   "username":"CAPAP3",
   "aht_value":"NA",
   "station":"B10"
  }
 ]
```

AJAX call:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#aht').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url : "show_aht.php",
                    data:{  } , // do I need to pass data if im GET ting?
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(data){
                        //going through all DIVs only once with this loop
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // loop over results
                            var divForResult = $('#desk_' + data[i]['station']); // look for div for this object
                            if(divForResult.length) { // if a div was found
```

**Here I output the background color and aht_value**

```
                                divForResult.html(data[i]['aht_value']).css("background-color", colorMe(data[i]['aht_value']));
                            }//end if
                            }//end for
                    }//end success
                });//end ajax   
              });//end click
            });//end rdy

            //function for background color
            function colorMe(v){
                    return "rgb(" + conv(v) + "," + (255-conv(v)) + ",0)";
            }
```

**here I want to check the lowest value from the array and highest to make the calculation
I added 1800 as t he highest and 100 as the lowest but I want it to be the values from the array**

```
            //function for calculation of background color depending on aht value               
            function conv(x){
                return Math.floor((x - 100) / (1800-100) * 255);
            }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your json file is not valid.
Ajax calls are using strict method, so if the json is not valid it will not get to your success function.

try debugging the json file here first: http://jsonlint.com/

try using this json (fixed):

```
[
  {
    "username": "OXGOR",
    "aht_value": "241",
    "station": "B20"
  },
  {
    "username": "AISAI2",
    "aht_value": "199",
    "station": "B21"
  },
  {
    "username": "CAPAP3",
    "aht_value": "NA",
    "station": "B10"
  }
]
```